# uri to real path in react-native

Tags: react-native, path, uri

I use react-native-document-picker to select images and videos in Android and IOS.
The problem is that it returns an uri, and I need the real path.

I tried using react-native-fetch-blob with function stat. And react-native-fs with function stat. Both don't work with uris. But if I use for example react-native-fs readFile, it works ok with uris.

react-native-get-real-path works only with Android so is not an option.

EDIT:
Someone advised me to use rn-fetch-blob, but I had problems installing it:
https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/289

I tried to use react-native-get-real-path and distinguish between Android and IOS, but it is problematic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used react-native-document-picker for ios and react-native-file-picker for android

Answer (score -1):

```
File file = new File(getURIPath(uriValue));

/**
 * URI Value
 * @return File Path.
 */
String getURIPath(Uri uriValue) 
    {
        String[] mediaStoreProjection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriValue, mediaStoreProjection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){ 
        int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String colIndexString=cursor.getString(colIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return colIndexString;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please format this code properly to make it a bit readable. :)